# Extract Model for Specific Factor

Tags: r

Say I've fit a model as follows `fit = lm(Y ~ X + Dummy1 + Dummy2)`

How can I extract the regression for a specific dummy variable?

I'm hoping to do something like the following to plot all the regressions:

```
plot(...)
abline(extracted.lm.dummy1)
abline(extracted.lm.dummy2)
```

Comment: There's also library(effects); plot(allEffects(fit)).

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the `sjPlot` package. [Here is the documentation](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.lm/) for `sjp.lm`, which can be used to visualize linear models in various ways. The package also has some nice tools for tabular summaries of models.

An example:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(dplyr)

# add a second categorical variable to the iris dataset
# then generate a linear model
set.seed(123)
fit <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 150, replace = TRUE))) %>%
  lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species + Category, data = .)
```

Different kinds of plot include:

Marginal effects plot, probably closest to what you want

```
sjp.lm(fit, type = "eff", vars = c("Category", "Species"))
```

[image]

"Forest plot" (beta coefficients + confidence interval)

```
sjp.lm(fit)
```

[image]